# Web API login with facebook external provider

Tags: asp.net, facebook, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity

I am having a hard time authenticating doing external authentication with Facebook on Web API. This is my controller to handle the Facebook button click.

```
[Route("facebooklogin", Name= "FacebookLogin")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
    public async Task<ActionResult> FacebookLogin()
    {
        string facebookLink = string.Empty;
        //Get available logins from api
        using(HttpClient client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri(Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)) })
        {
            var returnUrl = Url.RouteUrl("FacebookCallback");
            var url = "/api/Account/ExternalLogins?returnUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl + "&generateState=true");
            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var loginList = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<ExternalLoginViewModel>>();
                facebookLink = loginList.Where(x => x.Name == "Facebook").Select(x => x.Url).FirstOrDefault();
                //Send a get request to the facebook url
                var facebookUrlResponse = await client.GetAsync(facebookLink);
                facebookUrlResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            }
            else { }
        }
        return View();
    }

    [Route("facebookcallback", Name="FacebookCallback")]
    public ActionResult FacebookLoginCallback()
    {
        //Parse the access_token from facebook from the url


        return View();
    }
```

Whenenever i debug to `var facebookUrlResponse = await client.GetAsync(facebookLink);`, i realise i have a bad request. My code gets all the available external login providers and then try to use the url available generated for Facebook to hit the /api/Account/ExternalLogin endpoint in the account controller. I am unable hit that endpoint.

I get this error message:

> Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).

I plan to have the redirect uri come to the FacebookCallback route. Then i can parse the access_token from the uri and do further procession. Can anyone please help me out?

I could glean this info from postman:

> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>   Exception Details: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).

The source error is:

> //Send a get request to the facebook url
>   Line 135:                    var facebookUrlResponse = await client.GetAsync(facebookLink);

This is the stacktrace also:

> [HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).]
>      System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() +92180
>      Blinkas.Web.Controllers.<FacebookLogin>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Williams\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Blinkas\Blinkas.Web\Controllers\HomeController.cs:136
>      System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
>      System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
>      System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +26
>      System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThrowIfFaulted(Task task) +42
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +37
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +58
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +68
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +69
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +230
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +58
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +68
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +42
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +124
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +58
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +30
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +27
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +48
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +58
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +30
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +21
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +26
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +58
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +30
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +21
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +24
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +27
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +48
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +58
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +30
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +21
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +23
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +129

Comment: Check the response _body_, pretty sure there’s a readable error message in there.

Comment: I've added the error messages from postman

Comment: Did you find solution on this issue? I have very similar error..

Comment: I've put using Facebook app on hold. I will touch it later